# AttributeRouting is it possible to capture / inside of a parameter?

Tags: routes, asp.net-mvc-5, attributerouting

First let me be clear I am talking about the independent project of AttributeRouting http://attributerouting.net/ and not the built-in attribute routing.

Take this slightly modified version of their example code:

```
public class SampleController : Controller
{   
    [GET("Sample")]
    public ActionResult Index() { /* ... */ }
    [POST("Sample")]
    public ActionResult Create() { /* ... */ }
    [PUT("Sample/{id}")]
    public ActionResult Update(string id) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Suppose that for `Update` I wanted to have the request `PUT Sample/Cheese/Swiss` is there any way to inform AttributeRouting that the `id` parameter should capture "**Cheese/Swiss**"?

Comment: Yes I know I could use the request `PUT Sample/Cheese-Swiss` or similar which I may end up doing, but I'd prefer to able to achieve my original goal here.

Comment: Why not `Update(string product, string id)`? and `[PUT("Sample/{product}/{id})]`?  Then coalesce it in the method if necessary.

Comment: @tvanfosson also possible, but what if the id i want is Cheese/Swiss/Block or School/PennState/Program/SoftwareEngineering. I guess I could go the Tuple approach and have X methods that recompose the url and pass it down to a single shared method. My end goal is for targeting rather high levels of dynamicism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't [PUT("Sample/{*id}")] work? The asterisk means "take the rest".

Comment: That is not documented on their site and while I'm familiar with that usage from the built-in MVC catch-all routes I was unaware that was relevant to attribute routing.